# Cone Plane Intersection Radius Size

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have a cone which is passing through a plane. The cone is not perpendicular to the plane, so the intersection area between the cone and the plane will not be circular but an ellipse. The cone *will* appear to be perpendicular to the plane in the yz-plane, so the positive and negative z-radii will be equal.

Given the xy-plane cross section of the cone that looks as follows:

[image]

The negative x-radius, $\overline{SI}$, is shorter than the positive x-radius, $\overline{IL}$. My question is: Is the z-radii length equal to the average length of $\overline{SI}$ and $\overline{IL}$, that is the length of $\overline{SL}$ over 2?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Medium length answer: if the length of the $z$ radius was that of half of $SL$, this would mean that the intersection is a circle, which you know it is not...